Grafana promql alerts
Would like to seek for your help on letting me understand my promql grafana query.
Basically i have this query to calculate rx drops per minute and from what i understand on the for clause, it should stay having 100 drops/s for the next 5 minutes.
but what confuses me is that my would it alert somewhere when it was not consistent having 100 drops/s over 5 minutes



sum by(host)(rate(net_drop_in{}[1m]))>100
      - name: rx_drops
        rules:
          - alert: rx_drops
            expr: sum by(host,pop)(rate(net_drop_in{}[1m]))>100
            # Alert will be in pending state for at least 5 minutes
            for: 5m
            labels:
              severity: warning
            annotations:
              description: '{{ $labels.host }} : *{{ humanize $value }}*'
              summary: 'RX drops is high, with an average rate exceeding 100 drops/s over the last 5 minutes'


please help me on this. I wanted this alert to fire right
Tried to check the expression
